# passing data with cURL post, escaping characters?

Tags: php, curl, escaping

I have some post data as shown below, which I'm trying to send to a cURL function, which in turn sends the data to a POST form.

But when I run the script, I get a syntax error. I believe that it's being caused by the `"`. Normally, you could just escape these using a `\"` or change them to `'`, but I think that this will cause an error when submitted to the form. how can I handle this?

```
{"potential":[{"Id":"B-1_10732423478-6551232102-0-LM-0","marketId":"1.1012336578","selection":6350122,"size":2,"price":2.5,"asian":0,"categoryType":"E","version":2,"Limit":0,"marketName":"Drive 2013","marketType":"UNDIFFERENTIATED","eventId":"269256462","orderType":"LIMIT","fractional":{"numerator":null,"denominator":null},"runnerId":"1_105868-6552342-0","transactionId":null,"each":false,"runnerOrder":1,"side":"BACK","inplay":false}],"deDupToken":"1368190973413"}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'potential' (T_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/curl/index.php on line 16
```

Comment: Can you add the complete curl statement you are running?  Also please copy and paste the error that you are seeing.

Comment: You seem to be posting JSON, while curl expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it this true, or is this a post value in a larger string (in which case you can feed curl either an array or use `http_build_query`)?

Comment: @ronak please see the amended question, thanks

Comment: @wrikken yes, that was a snippet of a larger string, which ive now attached, this is the post string that ive got from tracking the post data using HttpFox, ill give it a shot with http_build_query